# I need html script for asking simple 1+2 = ? then delayed redirect

Tags: html, url, redirect

I want a html page with simple question 1 + 2 and when user puts 3 it delayed redirects to another url after 3 seconds?

Basically I want a code for this. I apologize if it's too broad or inapropriate. But I need help right now.

Comment: So, basically you are looking for someone to write this code for you?

Comment: Yes basically, it's not that im lazy it's just that i got my hands full with other stuff and i don't know html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommed asking people to write code for you on StackOverflow because this is a community where you ask questions and it gets answered. With that being said, I am bored so I will help you.

Using HTML and JQuery, we have an input and a button. When the button is pressed, it runs the function testInput(), which checks if the value of the input is equal to three, then if it is we wait 3 seconds then redirect them. Here is a working snippet:

```js
function testInput() {
    var inputVal = $("#inputBox").val();
    if (inputVal == "3") {
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href = "anotherpage.html";
        }, 3000);
      } else {
        alert("wrong");
        }
  }

function neverGunnaRun() {
   alert("CHANGE THIS IN EVERY PAGE");
  }
```

```html
1+2 = <input id="inputBox" type="text"> <button onclick="testInput();">Test</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** Change the "CHANGE THIS IN EVERY PAGE" in the alert function in every different page to something else, and it won't change a thing.

Comment: Hi thanks and I understand being kind of leecher to have put this 'code for me' but i have no other option :(

Comment: Hi thanks and I understand being kind of leecher to have put this 'code for me' but i have no other option :(
since you are bored :) another question. I need to put this code in 10 different landing pages. How can I make all 10 unique so a web crawler does not find them identical. I mean some random string or whatever ? [apoloegtic]

Comment: do you want the html to be unique? or the javascript?

Comment: If javascript can work within html page then javascript. I will upload single index file to public_html folder of different domains so i want them all to be unique.

Comment: Ok so you want the Javascript to be different on each pages. Before i do this can you upvote my answer and also check it as the correct answer so you aren't leeching?

Comment: I already did upvote http://prntscr.com/dkoieu

Comment: ok thanks. why exactly do you want each page to be different?

Comment: I want them to be different because same types of websites get flagged where I put them and not good for SEO

Comment: ill edit it to show where you can change something that won't affect it but you still need to manually change it for each website. give me a minute, i am out.

Comment: Ok im all ears :)
I will put manually in each page no problems.

Comment: Done! Next time be sure to ask a question instead of asking someone to do work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much i'll keep in mind. just one thing. Where do I put this function. button seems to be ok. check this:
http://prntscr.com/dkp1gm

Comment: You need to have this in your html page in script tags. `<script>function testInput() {
    var inputVal = $("#inputBox").val();
    if (inputVal == "3") {
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href = "anotherpage.html";
        }, 3000);
      } else {
        alert("wrong");
        }
  }

function neverGunnaRun() {
   alert("CHANGE THIS IN EVERY PAGE");
  }
</script>`
Have this at the bottom of your html page.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for being patient. anyway I can give a good rep or positive feedback ?

Comment: Let me start a chat with you so we don't spam comments.

Comment: Actually I can't you do not have enough rep..... You can go to my profile, then to Top Posts, then go to each one and upvote all my answers haha that would help.